# Как сгруппировать и подсчитать каждый элемент сериализованного массива?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, сериализация

Нужный мне плагин для Wordpress хранит список элементов в сериализованном массиве внутри поля в базе MySQL. Каждый пользователь имеет этот сериализованный массив в своей собственной таблице. Мне нужно подсчитать, сколько пользователей имеет один элемент сериализованного массива.

**Например:**

**User_id** | **Value**

**123**     | a:4:{i:0;s:3:”**615**“;i:1;s:3:”**619**“;i:2;s:3:”**918**“;i:3;s:3:”**570**“;}

**12**      | a:4:{i:0;s:3:”**23**“;i:1;s:3:”**615**“;i:2;s:3:”**918**“;}

**143**     | a:4:{i:0;s:3:”**918**“;i:1;s:3:”**125**“;}

**Нужно получить и вывести:**

918 – имеет 3 юзера

615 – имеет 2 юзера

619 – имеет 1 юзер

570 – имеет 1 юзер

125 – имеет 1 юзер

23 – имеет 1 юзер

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: всё можно сделать в sql запросе, или выгрузить в массив через php и посчитать в массиве одинаковые совпадения.

Comment: С точки зрения MySQL показанные значения - обычная строка (не JSON) - вот и обрабатывай её как строку. Извлекай отдельные значения (например, в рекурсивном CTE), а потом группируй и подсчитывай.

Comment: А вот спроектировал бы базу нормально - не страдал бы от такого.

Comment: @u_mulder так это же Wordpress и непонятный плагин написанный непонятно кем, о какой нормальной базе вы говорите?

Comment: @Kvandaik если не сложно подскажи, пожалуйста, как это сделать через sql запрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача достаточно тривиальна.

1. Забираем данные из базы
2. Десериализуем и объединяем в один массив
3. Считаем количество значений

```php
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Users;";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    //Unserialize and join user arrays
    $count_users = array_reduce(
        $users,
        function($res, $u) {
            return array_merge($res, unserialize($u['Value']));
        },
        []
    );
    
    //Print count values
    print_r(array_count_values($count_users));
```

[Test PHP array_reduce unserialize array_merge](https://phpize.online/?phpses=02941e65f199e6826f709171fc488502&sqlses=17772f92c6028550d38f60e5ef7f9eb8&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, добрый человек!